# Free software for creating fillable PDFs

Tags: pdf, forms, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

I'm looking for Adobe Acrobat DC alternative (https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/how-to/create-fillable-pdf-forms-creator.html) - PDF creator capable of creating PDF fillable forms.
Is there something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Office lets you embed form elements, and then export the doc as a fillable PDF using FDF to submit.

Comment: This should be more known feature of OpenOffice. A lot of people are buying Acrobat for this and OpenOffice can do this simple thing without any problems. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use Scribus but that might be overkill.

Comment: @OndrejVrabel no problem. I only use it to create a FDF PDF form template so I can dynamically populate the fields via code and then flatten the PDF to make it un-editable to generate certificates, etc.

Comment: @ivanivan is there a way to change the font in the field?

Comment: @OndrejVrabel - Yup.  Double click on the field and you'll get properties for it, scroll down to see size, face, style, etc.  For my use, I turn off the borders on input fields, also done in that same properties area

Comment: Thanks. This just made it so much better. I'm happy! I wasn't expecting for perfect answer to my question..